# If function for CSS selector - GTM

Tags: javascript, if-statement, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I have very basic JS knowledge, so excuse me for such simple question.

How to create if function for the following situation:

```
if "CSS selector'= a, return 'text1'
if 'CSS selector'= b, return 'text2'
if 'CSS selector'= c, return ''text3'
otherwise return 'not set'
```

I need this to return the product category depending on clicked button. Click class/id is the same for all 3 buttons.

Thank You

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a Google Tag Manager solution (since you added the tag)? Also if the id is the same on all three buttons then your code is broken, since ids are supposed to be unique. Won't matter in most scenarios, but makes targeting the element harder and might break JS that interacts with the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

should be `if ("CSS selector'=== a) { return 'text1'}`